# How do I find data from this day exactly one year ago in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Merry Christmas,

I am using the below query to get the prices, but my requirement is to get the data for last one year from trunc(sysdate). i have tried using DATEADD function but its gives me an error

*`cast(p.asof as DATE) = cast(DATEADD(Year, -1, GETDATE()) as DATE)`*

```
select idvalue, p.asof as DATE_, p.instrument, p.price
from instruments i
inner join prices_equity_closing p on p.instrument = i.pkey
inner join instruments_ids id on i.ids = id.idset
where
id.idvalue in ('MRVE3.SA')
and id.idtype in ('RIC')
and p.asof = trunc(sysdate)-1
order by i.exchange, i.type, p.asof desc;
```

Can anyone please help, what all changes i require to get the desired result ?

Comment: Some handy links: [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/book-index.html), [SQL Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use add_months and sysdate:

```
select add_months(sysdate,-12) x from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract an INTERVAL of 12 months from the current date.

```
... 
where
id.idvalue in ('MRVE3.SA')
and id.idtype in ('RIC')
and p.asof >= trunc(sysdate) - interval '12' month
order by i.exchange, i.type, p.asof desc;
```

Comment: Hi Luk, it is working but only giving price for 25dec 2020, i need all the prices for last 365 days

Comment: and trunc(p.asof) > trunc(sysdate) - interval '12' month    this worked

Comment: That's easy, just change `=` to `>=`

Comment: I also removed the first trunc. With `>=` it doesn't matter that asof can have hours/minutes/seconds. And it makes it sargable.

Comment: This will error if run on February 29th. But for this sort of check it's often more useful to truncate to the first of the month, which will always work. As will `add_months`, though the OP needs to understand the behaviour of that too.

Comment: @AlexPoole So it's a risk to get an error every 4 years on 1 day.  I've seen worse ;) Thx for the warning.

Answer (score -1):

or we can simply use and p.asof > trunc(sysdate)-365

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: And not all years have 365 days, of course...